# Unable to suppress Checkstyle test on method with SuppressionXpathSingleFilter

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am using Checkstyle 10.5 within IntelliJ 2022.3.1. I would like to suppress magic number checks within test methods by using `SuppressionXpathSingleFilter` in the configuration file. I prefer not to use a separate suppressions file because my configuration file will be shared, and I do not want to annotate the source to disable checks.

### Source file `MyTest.java`

```
class MyTest {
    public int testOne() {
        return 95;
    }

    public int TestTwo() {
        return 96;
    }
}
```

There are 3 style errors:

- a magic number in `testOne()`
- a bad method name in `TestTwo()`
- a magic number in `TestTwo()`

### Configuration file `test-checks.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="MethodName"/>
    <module name="MagicNumber"/>

    <module name="SuppressionXpathSingleFilter">
      <property name="files" value="MyTest.java"/>
      <property name="checks" value="MagicNumber"/>
      <property name="query" value="//METHOD_DEF[./IDENT[@text='testOne']]"/>
    </module>
  </module>
</module>
```

### Expected result

When I run checkstyle, I expect to see only violations in `TestTwo`:

```
Name 'TestTwo' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. (6:16) [MethodName]
'96' is a magic number. (7:16) [MagicNumber]
```

### Actual result

I actually still see the magic number violation in `testOne()`:

```
'95' is a magic number. (3:16) [MagicNumber]
Name 'TestTwo' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. (6:16) [MethodName]
'96' is a magic number. (7:16) [MagicNumber]
```

### What I've tried

I have tried different path values in `test-checks.xml`, such as:

```
"//CLASS_DEF[@text='MyTest']/OBJBLOCK/METHOD_DEF[@text='testOne']/IDENT"
```

No matter what I do, the result is the same. **How do I disable a specific check within a specific method without a separate suppression file or annotating the code?**

Comment: escape `.` with \ in `<property name="files" value="MyTest.java"/>`

Comment: Thanks @Juraj, but doing this made no difference: `<property name="files" value="MyTest\.java"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `SuppressionXpathSingleFilter` documentation](https://checkstyle.org/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/filters/SuppressionXpathSingleFilter.html) is confusing and it seems it contains outdated examples. If you check the [`XPathFilterElement`](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/098d9c0d764f1d1d92cdcf192e71f56e40e0b68c/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/filters/XpathFilterElement.java#L192) you can see the XPath expression must match the AST leaf node so the easiest way to fix the XPath `query` property is to add a wildcard at the end:

```
  <property name="query" value="//METHOD_DEF[./IDENT[@text='testOne']]//*"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

to suppress by xpath you need to know AST node where checkstyle place violation on.

Look at https://checkstyle.org/cmdline.html#Command_line_usage
there is `[-g | --generate-xpath-suppression]`

it will print you xpath. it might be a bit verbose and you can shrink it by usage of leading `//` at place you need.

Checks that does not have support of Xpath yet: https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html#SuppressionXpathFilter_Description

Unfortunately MagicNumber did not get test example of suppression
https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/098d9c0d764f1d1d92cdcf192e71f56e40e0b68c/src/test/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/internal/XpathRegressionTest.java#L114 ,
you can put your bounty on https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/6207 fix it sooner.

if you need xpath suppression examples for other Checks, look at https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/tree/master/src/it/java/org/checkstyle/suppressionxpathfilter